# How to get value dropdowns in yii2

Tags: javascript, html, yii2

I am trying to do a Yii2 application.
I want to make highcharts in yii 2. these highcharts will change depending on the input that comes from the dropdown. 
I can not retrieve the value from the dropdown for use in the showby function.
how can i retrieve value from dropdown?

This is my code Controller below.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new kntnRPemesananSearch();
    $options =  new RBarangSearch();

$data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select week(tanggal)+1 as tanggal,harga,nama from kntn_r_barang_masuk where nama = "beras" group by tanggal')->queryAll();
//print_r($data);
return $this->render('index', ['ddiagram' => $data,'model'=> $searchModel,'opt'=>$options]);

}

public function actionShowBy($nama_barang){
    $searchModel = new kntnRPemesananSearch();
    $options =  new RBarangSearch();

$data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select week(tanggal)+1 as tanggal,harga,nama from kntn_r_barang_masuk where nama ="'.$nama_barang.'" group by tanggal')->queryAll();
//print_r($data);
return $this->render('index', ['ddiagram' => $data,'model'=> $searchModel,'opt'=>$options]);

}
```

}

and this my code view

```html
<div class="form_pemesanan">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
   <div class="field_input">
       <?= $form->field($opt, 'nama_barang')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(RBarang::find()->all(),'nama_barang','nama_barang'),['prompt'=>'Barang']); 
       ?>
       
       <?= Html::a('Pilih', ['grafik/show-by','nama_barang'=>$opt->nama_barang], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="field_input col-sm-offset-11">
    <?
    
    ?>
       
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

how can i retrieve value from dropdowns and send value from dropdown to function showby?
thanks before.

Comment: Try to regard it as a client-side issue. i.e javascript issue. It is not related with Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to use Pjax, like this:

controller:

```
public function actionAbout()
{
    return $this->render('about', ['time' => time(), 'data' => null]);
}

public function actionAbout2()
{
    return $this->renderPartial('about', ['time' => time(), 'data' => Yii::$app->request->post() ]);
}
```

view:

```
<hr>
<?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]) ?>
<form data-pjax="" method="POST" action="<?= Url::to(['site/about2']) ?>">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="<?= $time; ?>">
    <br>
    <code>post data: <?= print_r($data, true); ?></code>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

what's going on here is:

1. initial render code within Pjax
2. mark a form (or link) with 'data-pjax=""'
3. now you optionally can change then form's action
4. submit will now replace the HTML enclosed by Pjax

[read more here](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2)